# How file structure works and routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, mean.io

I already created a MEAN project with mean.io. But when I open the file structure there are some stuff I don't understant. The sample html that MEAN provides it's inside of system/public/views/index.html and when I change any HTML code. Like just to realize I'm changing the file I want.

[image: Adding some text]

And instantly the browser returns me an error:

```
Cannot GET /
```

And even is I create a new file like test.html. In system/public/routes/system.js where all routes are located I got this.

```
$meanStateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'system/views/index.html'
  })

.when('/test', {
        templateUrl : 'system/views/test.html'
});
```

And when i execute

```
localhost:3000/test
```

the browser returns me the same error I mentioned before.

```
Cannot GET /test
```

What am I missing?

///////////
Review:

I added the following code:

```
 .state('test', {
    url: '/test',
    templateUrl: 'system/views/test.html'
  })
```

And that worked for the test page but for the home page is not working.

Comment: Try remove the '/' in '/test'

Comment: I added a solution I found. But what I don't understant if I change only one character on HTML (home page) then the browser displays the error commented above.